# Как из тетрады (полубайта) создать отдельный байт? Assembler/TASM

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Нужно например из F0 1А  (двубайтного кода) получить массив

```
0F 00 01 0А
```

---

Не знаю, как это реализовать в TASM

Comment: shr и and вам в помощь. Бежите по своим байтам циклом младшую тетраду выделяете and al, 0Fh, старшую - shr al,4

Comment: @Mike Я вот так и сделал, и вроде правильно сделал. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, что-то типа приведенного далее кода (исходное число - в `ax`, результат - в `eax`).

```
mov ecx, eax          ;eax = 0000F01A  ecx = 0000F01A
and eax, 0000ff00H    ;      0000F000        0000F01A
shl eax, 8            ;      00F00000        0000F01A
and ecx, 000000ffH    ;      00F00000        0000001A
or  eax, ecx          ;      00F0001A        0000001A
mov ecx, eax          ;      00F0001A        00F0001A
shl eax, 4            ;      0F0001A0        00F0001A
or  eax, ecx          ;      0FF001BA        00F0001A
and eax, 0f0f0f0fH    ;      0F00010A        00F0001A
```

Ужался в 9 строк и 2 регистра :)

Comment: Лучше написать что исходное число в AX, старшие два байта же не используются

Comment: @Mike Используются - на выходе. Тогда я первое, что должен делать - нулить старшее слово `eax`. Так, как мне кажется, меньше телодвижений... Нет, соврал, вы правы: первый же `and` его и так обнулит.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, теперь понял

Comment: @papalimer Пожалуйста :) Тогда помечайте ответ как принятый :)

Comment: Первые 5 строк можно заменить на movzx eax,ax; shl eax,8; shr ax,8; Причем первая инструкция может быть заменена на загрузку 2х байт исходных данных из памяти

Comment: @Mike Охотно поверю - я все больше по C++, ассемблер - это так, воспоминания молодости...